# List data from different table, group based on ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am beginner in MySQL. I have question about displaying data from two different table (same database), and list them based on their ID.

> Recently, I am doing my project about creating simple discussion board
>   (chat style) with features another user can comment to a post.

I have 2 tables,

**Shoutbox** -> Record a Discussion submit by an user

> **ID  | Name   | Text  |** 
>   1     | Iqbal   | This is Question   | 
>  2     | Zizan  | Another Question  |

**Comment** ->> Record a Comment from another user

> **ID | Comment   |** 
>  1  | Answer for Iqbal | 
>   1     |  Another answer for Iqbal   | 
>  2  | Answer for Zizan |

How do I display *Comment*, according to Data in *Shoutbox* (based on their ID) ?

**So, it should like this**

> Discussion Board
>
> Iqbal : This is Question 
>  Answer : Answer for Iqbal 
>  Answer : Another Answer for Iqbal
>
> Zizan : Another Question 
>  Answer : Answer for Zizan

Comment: you have 2 databases or 2 table?

Comment: 2 table in 1 database .

Comment: can there be multiple answers to same question? i mean the ID in comment table, either its a foreign key or primary for comment table?

Comment: Check this SQLFIDDLE: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d2ba/10)

Comment: Yes, we can have answers from multiple user to answer on the same question. I haven't set key for ID comment yet. Note : ID from Comment is the same with ID in Shoutbox. With this I mean the Comment will refer to the Shoutbox.

Comment: It can be done better with at least 3 tables : `user` , `question` , `answer` .

Comment: how it can be done @Uours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `Shoutbox`
LEFT JOIN `Comment` 
ON `Shoutbox`.ID = `Comment`.ID
```

Of course to show data you will have a while loop do this in your `while`

```
while ( ... ) {

   echo $r['Name'] . ' : ' . $r['Text'];
   echo '<br />';
   echo 'Answer :' . $r['Comment'];

   echo '<br /> <br />';
}
```

**Edit:**

If you have multiple Answers against each `Shoutbox` then you need to do the following.

Notice the change in the query

```
SELECT * FROM `Shoutbox`
RIGHT JOIN `Comment` 
ON `Shoutbox`.ID = `Comment`.ID
```

and the following code

```
$finaleArray = array();
while ( $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {

   $id = $r['ID'];

   if ( !isset($finaleArray[$id]['question']) ) {
      $finaleArray[$id]['question'] = $r['Text'];
      $finaleArray[$id]['name'] = $r['Name'];
   }

   $finaleArray[$id]['answer'][] = $r['Comment'];
}

foreach( $finaleArray as $id => $a ) {
   echo $a['name'] . ' : ' . $a['question'];
   foreach($a['answer'] as $ans) {
      echo '<br />';
      echo 'Answer :' . $ans;
   }
   echo '<br /> <br />';
}
```

Of course there are confusions in the above code, you should ask if you don't understand anything.

Comment: @iqbalplague please check, I hope this will help, let me know if you have any query regarding `while` code

Comment: the first code is working, but with single comment on single question (One question and one comment).  The second code give me output "Answer :  " in each line, without any text. could you help me solve this?

Comment: the while statement in 2nd code, is for $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result), right?

Comment: it should work, can you show me what you have tried,, show me while and other loop.. do edit your question and add the code after **Edit:**

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` yes and i made it `$r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change $r with $row, since my while code using $row. Finally It's working... :) Thank you @zzlaini

Comment: it's working for question that have comment , but if there is no comment (just question), it doesn't appear. I will check again the code. :)

Comment: I see.. just make a change in the query `RIGHT JOIN Comment ` to `JOIN Comment ` and let me know the results, sorry for late reply

Comment: @iqbalplague please check is it what you are looking for? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd255/1 if yes then we need to the the query to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: yes, something like that. but i want to display comment (in a list form) under the question. If you don't mind, take a look at this. http://hna-consulting.com/demo/example.JPG .

Comment: so is your query fix now?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM Shoutbox
INNER JOIN Comment 
ON Shoutbox.ID = Comment.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

make another field `Shoutbox_id`  under Comment TABLE, while inserting value under Comment table passed Shoutbox primay id in Comment TABLE >> `Shoutbox_id`

and then use JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM `Shoutbox` as s
LEFT JOIN `Comment` as c
ON s.id = c.Shoutbox_id
```